# laravel redirectTo not working for custom controller

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I am new in Laravel . want to use redirectTo property in my custom controller after registration . registration is working fine , but redirect is not working

My custom controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Login;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController as DefaultLoginController;
use App\Employee;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
class EmployeeController extends Controller
{
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest:employee')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('employee');
    }
    public function register()
    {
        return Employee::create(['employee_id'=>12, 'employee_password'=>2]);
}
}
```

i added providers in my config/Auth.php

```
<?php

return [


    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
        'passwords' => 'employee',
    ],


    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'employee',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'employee',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
        'employee' => [
            'redirectTo' => 'employee.home',
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'employee',
           ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'employee' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Employee::class,
           ],
    ],



    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
        'employee' => [
            'provider' => 'employee',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

and my Employee class in app folder

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Employee extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = ['employee_id', 'employee_password'];

];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

my RedirectIfAuthenticated middleware

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

still redirect not working . What Am I missing ? Let me know if I am missing any code to show

Comment: can you share your `RedirectIfAuthenticated` Middleware? This is where you should put your logic: `switch($guard){...}`

Comment: sure  , I put on this class , please suggest

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
if(Employee::create(['employee_id'=>12, 'employee_password'=>2]))
   return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: thats good logic , working . but still I want to learn How default auth is working in behind

Comment: This would work only for registration, not for login

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the redirect directly from your `RedirectIfAuthenticated` Middleware as follow:

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            if($guard)
                 return redirect()->route(config('auth.guards.' . $guard . '.redirectTo'));
            return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

As well, remove `protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;` from your custom controller

Comment: not working ... even i clear config cache and restart

Comment: Can you please `dd($guard);` in the Middleware when testing redirect as an employee?

Comment: even tried  dd(Auth::guard($guard)->check()); it showing false after register

Comment: That's strange, what does `dd(config('auth.' . $guard . '.redirectTo'))`

Comment: is it anyy issue in config/auth.php provider or guard key / values

Comment: Sorry I can't screenShare - please check the updated code (my `config()` was wrong)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212602/discussion-between-neeraj-verma-and-christophe-hubert).